# How to make a child clickable in an expandlelistview

Tags: android

I have an expandableListView in a Fragment If i click on an child I want it to open an activity / fragment with some content. Below is my listview

public class TodoFragment extends Fragment {

```
public TodoFragment(){}

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_todo,container, false);
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);


    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    // Listview Group click listener
    expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, long id) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
            // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }
    });

    // Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                            + " : "
                            + listDataChild.get(
                                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                    childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Culture");
    listDataHeader.add("Beaches");
    listDataHeader.add("Car Rental");
    listDataHeader.add("Dinner");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> culture= new ArrayList<String>();
    culture.add("Grotten van Hato");
    culture.add("Ostrich Farm");
    culture.add("Shete Boka national Park");
    culture.add("Landhuis Knip");
    culture.add("Christoffelpark");
    culture.add("Navy Museum");
    culture.add("Post Museum");

    List<String> beaches = new ArrayList<String>();
    beaches.add("Mambo Beach");
    beaches.add("Knip");
    beaches.add("Playa Kalki");
    beaches.add("Westpunt");
    beaches.add("Boca Santa Cruz");
    beaches.add("Cas Abao");
    beaches.add("Playa PortoMari");
    beaches.add("Kontiki Beach");
    beaches.add("Jan Thiel Beach");

    List<String> car = new ArrayList<String>();
    car.add("budget rental");
    car.add("Avis Rental");
    car.add("Alamo Car Rental");
    car.add("Noordstar Rental");
    car.add("Europa Rental");

    List<String> dinner = new ArrayList<String>();
    dinner.add("Truk di Pan");
    dinner.add("Burger King");
    dinner.add("Punda Food");


    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), culture); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), beaches);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), car);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), dinner);

}
```

}

can anyone help me out please.

Comment: You can use Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class); startActivity(intent); this code inside onChildClick method, and you can set data to intent which you want to use in next activity.

Comment: Thanks Rajiv, what i don't really get is were to place it and do i need to do this for every child. How does android know what child is been clicked on. Can You help me with that please

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

// Listview on child click listener

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        //You have to create next activity say NextActivity.java
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rajiv, i am so sorry for not understanding it correct. If  i do this i get a fault at context. How does android know what child i click. Like in my example for instance Grotten van Hato or Kontiki Beach. Can you help me with this please

Comment: I have corrected the issue. You can use getActivity() for a context

Comment: Sorry for my late response earlier it has been a while. I am able to click on the child in the listview but, what i really would like to do click each child and open a different activity. Can you or someone please help me with this.

Comment: In onChildClick method you are getting groupPosition and childPosition. Using these two attribute you can make a decision which activity has to be opened.

Comment: Thank you so much Rajiv. I found what i have been doing wrong. I am using a fragment, and that is why it aint working. I am trying to figure out how to leave child go to a other fragment